# Ember Bootstrap Dropdown

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am trying to use a pre-existing component to create a Bootstrap dropdown in Ember. The component API can be found here [Ember Bootstrap Dropdown API](http://kaliber5.github.io/ember-bootstrap/api/classes/Components.Dropdown.html). How do I make Ember aware of what the user selects? I can do it if I don't use that component but I was hoping to use it. Here is what I have:

```
{{#bs-dropdown}}
  {{#bs-button}}
    <strong>Select a File</strong>
  {{/bs-button}}
  {{#bs-dropdown-button}}
    <span class="caret"></span>
  {{/bs-dropdown-button}}
  {{#bs-dropdown-menu}}
    {{#each list as |item|}}
      <li>
        <a value={{item.title}}>{{item.title}}</a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/bs-dropdown-menu}}
{{/bs-dropdown}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire an action to update the clicked item.

```html
<li {{action 'clickItem' item}}>
```

You pass the data (items) down to the components and action up to parent components (Data down, actions up).

```js
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  click: function(item) {
    this.sendAction('clickItem', item);
  }
});
```

In the controller or route you can handle the action.

```js
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend(
  actions: {
    clickItem: function(item) {
      item.set('active', true);
    }
  }
});
```

Find more information here -> https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/